# Jenkins: How to put a new job for each scm-change into the build-queue?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, polling

I am using Jenkins for Continous-Integration.

I configured a job, which polls the scm for changes. I have one executor. When there is more than one scm-change, but the executor is already working, there is still only one job added to queue, where I want it to queue more than one job.

I already tried my job "parametrized" as a workaround, but as long as polling does not set any parameters¹ (even not the default ones²), this does not help, too.

Is there any way to get for each scm-change a new build in the job-queue?

[1] https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build

[2] I tried to combine this scenario with https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Dynamic+Parameter+Plug-in

Comment: Think carefully about the idea of having 1 build per SCM change.  It works as long as long as the SCM changes don't happen faster than a build can finish.  If the builds are slower than SCM changes can be made, then you run into the case where you will never be able to build the latest version.  (Work the case where SCM changes every minute, but the build takes just over 2 minutes.  By the time the 1st build is done, there are already 2 builds to start.  By the time the 2nd is done, there are 3 to be started, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Described scenario is possible in Jenkins by using a workaround which requires two steps:

- [JobA_trigger] One Job which triggers another job 'externally', via curl or jenkins-cli.jar¹.
- [JobA] The actual job which has to be a parametrized one.

In my setup, JobA_trigger polls SCM periodically. If there is a change, JobA is triggered via curl and the current dateTime is submitted². This 'external' triggering is necessary to submit parameters to JobA.

```
# JobA_trigger "execute shell"
curl ${JENKINS_URL}job/JobA/buildWithParameters?SVN_REVISION=`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`%20`date +"%H:%M:%S"`
# SVN_REVISION, example (decoded): "2012-11-07 12:56:50" ("%20" is url-encoded space)
```

JobA itself is parametrized and accepts a String-Param "SVN_REVISION". Additionally I had to change the SVN-URL to

```
# Outer brackets for usage of SVN revision dates³ - must be avoided if working on a revision-number.
https://svn.someaddress.com/trunk@{${SVN_REVISION}}
```

Using this workaround, for each scm-change there is new run of JobA queued which has the related svn-revision/dateTime attached as a parameter and is used as the software-state which is being tested by this job.

¹ https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI

² I decided to have dateTime-bases updates instead of revision-based ones, as I have svn-externals which would be updated to HEAD each, if I would be working revision-based.

³ http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html#svn.tour.revs.dates

Answer (score 1):

You can write a script with the [Jenkins Adaptive Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Adaptive+Plugin) to be triggered by SVN and create a new build regardless of what is currently running.

Another option would be to create two jobs, one that monitors SCM and one that runs the build. Every time there is an SCM change you have the first job add an instance of the second to the queue and complete immediately so that it can continue to poll.

Comment: Seconde option, you mean via Downstream-job? I tried it, doesn't help: "PROJECT_X #109 is already in the queue" (where "PROJECT_X" is the name of the job).

Comment: Second option is the correct one - just need to switch-off the **advanced build option** that blocks new builds while downstream jobs.

Comment: Gonen - that's not correct, a second or third job is not queued as "PROJECT_X #109 is already in the queue" is omitted.

Comment: @MarcusSchultö try making PROJECT_X a parameterized build and see if that gets it to queue multiple instances.

Comment: I solved the problem meanwhile, thanks to your replies! For clarification I added a new answer.
This discussed approach (using one job to trigger another one) was correct but missing the important trick: Triggering the actual job not via Downstream or similar, but using the remote-API of Jenkins.